# Firing web request for each item in *ngFor

Tags: angular

Using Angular, I have created a table that contains types of documents and their associated systems. Using `*ngFor` I can loop through items in an array named `this.doctypes` and get each document type's title and its associated system. However, I need to fire a web request that gets the system's location. I can do this with JavaScript with a common for loop but I'd like to do it within the `*ngFor`.

[I have created a Stackblitz for this.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbdad6)

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**
Per @Eliseo's suggestion I have created an object array with `.map`. However, I'm unsure how to combine this new array with `forkJoin`.

Comment: Hey the get requests are not responding right.

Comment: Don't loop over the *ngFor, loop over your data creating an Array of Observable (use map for this). Then use forkJoin to get all the request and join the request to your data. Then you can use *ngFor over the "extended" data

Comment: Ideally you just make 1 request for all the items, rather than 1 request per item.